# Google Charts - Filtering on Column Headings or Delimited Data within a Column

Tags: charts, google-visualization

We use Google Charts and have multiple filters on columns that work nicely, but I'm trying to work out how to filter either using specific column headings or using delimited data within a column.

I do have control over the data arrays being sent to the charts so I could do it either way.

The data I am trying to filter on is for job roles. So a person may be able to do multiple roles, for example, cook, waiter, bar staff, and security.

If I make each of the roles a column, and put yes/no in the data then when I apply filters I have one filter for each job, with a Yes/No option.
But what I want to have is one filter that has all the jobs, and when you choose one it shows the users that can do that role.

So I either need to be able to filter based on data in the columns, or I could make a single column called "Role" and put delimited data in that column for each user, for example, "cook, waiter, bar staff, security", but then my filter needs to not show all that text, but break it up into the delimited values within that text.

Comment: *Google Charts* or *Google Chart API*?

Comment: Using Google Charts

Comment: That just gives me all the text options in the column. Eg "cook, waiter", "waiter, bar staff", "waiter, bar staff, security". It doesn't give me just the individual delimited values of "cook", "waiter", "bar staff" and "security". If I set the values array directly in the CategoryFilter to list them one at a time then when I choose one of them it shows the ones that ONLY had that data in the column, not those that included that text.